# Cordova and IOs width issue

Tags: ios, node.js, cordova

We've uploaded a Cordova/Node app on Apple Store, but it was rejected, the problem is, the app isn't fitting on IOS grid, is not fitting 100% of the screen, is working well on Android, safari browser, the only problem is on IOs devices.

[Here's the example provided by apple:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4ySz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this meta tag to the `head` section of your `index.html`?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />
```

Also, what does your CSS file look like? Specifically, regarding html, body, and your main content div? Always use `width:100%`, not specific values in pixels.